# How can I use the app engine SDK dev_server.py to serve services from different repos?

Tags: google-app-engine

So what I want is this:

```
~/
  API service/
    App.yaml
    A big ol Python back end for a rest api/
    Dispatch.yaml
       /API -> default
       /* -> frontend static service
  Frontend static site/
     App.yaml
     Index.html
     Bundle.js <- a client side SPA. Talks to other thing via API calls
```

Note that the front end and backends are completely segregated directories. They do not know about each other at all. I want to run dev_server on my machine, such that my local environment knows about my dispatch.yaml rules, and correctly routes requests accordingly between different ports. But there is no Python app or anything in the front end. It's just an HTML file that loads a script tag. App engine knows how to serve that in prod. I don't see how to do it locally though.

Can it be done? What's the command? Do I run dev_server in both directories? Do I feed both app.yamls to a single command run from above both repos? I just don't get this. The docs are so opaque.

Comment: try `dev_appserver.py "API service/App.yaml" "Frontend static site/App.yaml"` on your local machine to run both default as well as front-end service.

Comment: and better to put dispatch.yaml in the project's root directory. On deployment, update it using `appcfg.py -A project-id update_dispatch`

Comment: Hey @AvinashRaj, great advice. The problem is that we don't want to have a project directory that contains all the services. We want them to live totally  discretely. But _some repo_ needs to be in charge of the dispatch file, or else it couldn't be source controlled, and it doesn't make much sense to have a repo _just_ for the dispatch file. So we'll have to figure out the best command for local dev given a similar directory structure.